# Qt Designer and QGIS, using relation references

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, widget, qt-designer

I have made my own form in Qt Designer and connected it to QGIS. One of my fields is a relation reference. 
But the text doesn't fit in the combo box. You can see it in the picture. [image]

I tried to change different settings in Qt Designer but it didn't help. Maybe someone can tell me how to change the size of a combo box in relation reference widget?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: What Settings did you try, did you learn ALL about Layouts before playing with Widgets?

Comment: I've tried to change geometry width and height. I made my form size on all window.  But some of my relation reference widget's combo boxes are too big and some too small. And all of them displayed in one line. It will be great to displayed combo boxes in several lines.

About setting. I also tried change size Policy, min and max size of iteam, size of Increament and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In the Property Dialog of the Widget change the Size Policy for Horizontal to Expanding and the "Drop Down" bit will get bigger as it is dragged. Although dragging it will make the "Drop Down" bar longer it will never exceed half of the total length of the whole tool.